# Iterate ArrayList through Hashmap to find unused element

Tags: java, hashmap

Trying to make an application User management system and suddenly came to a problem. I have an `ArrayList` of groups f.e. {Group1, Group2, Group3}. If I assign `user` to one group I put it into `HashMap` where {key, value} is {user, group}. And if no `user` is assigned to `group`, when I want to delete this `group`. How to find out which of the `group` wasn't used?

Comment: make a loop on ArrayList of groups and use method HashMap.containsValue() put it in if condition & so you can delete if the condition is true

Comment: `list.retainAll(map.values());`

Comment: @shmosel nice..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have `ArrayList<Group> groups` and `HashMap<User, Group> userMap` then you can find the group with no user with:

```
Set<Group> mappedGroup = new HashSet<>(userMap.values());
groups.removeIf(mappedGroup::contains); /? After this `groups` is unmapped groups list
```

The precondition is `Group` class already implement `equals/hashcode`

If you don't want to modified your original `groups` list, then you can do:

```
List<Group> unmappedGroups = groups.stream().filter(g -> !mappedGroup.contains(g))
                                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Your first snippet does the opposite of what OP asked for. And it doesn't compile.

Comment: _How to find out which of the group wasn't used_ I think I read OP's statement clearly

Comment: Yes, but your code removes the values that are used.

Comment: Did you read my answer yet? I already provided two versions, I don't know what's bothering you :)

Comment: I thought I was pretty clear. The first version doesn't compile and does the opposite of what was requested. What are you confused about?

Comment: You need to read the OP's statement again. He wants to find out which one wasn't not used, so we must filter out the group was used (which is in `mappedGroup`). For the compile error, I updated it. Thanks

Comment: Ok, I think we understood OP's request differently. My understanding is that he wants to remove unused goals from the list, not to retain them. If your code compiled, it would certainly help clarify your intent.

Comment: I want to filter out UNUSED group. @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn was right with the first answer

Comment: Yeah, then `unmappedGroups` is what you looking for, right :D

Comment: @Mellowas What does that mean? Do you want to select them or remove them? Either way, you can accomplish it with a simple `retainAll()` or `removeAll()`.

Comment: F.e. I have an Array with names = {Peter, John, Mike}, and Array with groups = {Group1, Group2}. Imagine, that all the members was assigned to Group1, so the Group2 is left. <--- I wanted to sort group2

Comment: @Mellowas Ok, but from the question it sounded like you want to delete group2.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the map values to a HashSet for constant time look up like following

```
Set<String> usedGroups = new HashSet<>(map.values());
```

Then checking can be done in the following way

```
for (String group : list) {
     if (usedGroups.contains(group)) { ... }
}
```